# How to efficiently organize based on rule?

Tags: algorithms

I am searching for an optimized way of doing the have the following scenario. With two classes: Wrapper and Child. My goal is to organize the child objects inside the Wrapper class based on some rules.

### Scenario

```
class Wrapper {
    int id;
    List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
    int id;
    int score;
}

Child mainChild;
```

1. There are **N objects of type Wrapper with also M children** inside each.
2. Each Wrapper has an id used for the sorting.
3. In one of the Wrapper objects there's **one child** which is **equal to the mainChild**.
4. All children in all Wrappers have a score which says if a child (except child which is equal to the main child) belongs together with the main child. (They should be in the same wrapper).
5. A child is only allowed to go to an existing wrapper if it is above the score (which means they belong together. If it is bellow, it should either stay in the wrapper or go to a new one (while trying to maintain the rules bellow)
6. New wrappers are allowed to be created.

**The goal is to have the main child in the same Wrapper with all the children (from any Wrapper) that have a score above X (let's say 2). And all bellow keep separated or separate from main child.**

### Rules

**The two rules of the sorting are**: the **wrappers with lower ids should** be preferred to **survive** instead of creating new wrappers. **Reduce** to the minimum the amount of **moves** of children between wrappers. The survivorship of the wrappers with lower ids have priority over quantity of moves.

### Examples

For easier illustration here is a scenario:

> Example 1: in this case the optimal arrangement maintains wrapper 1 and 2 while doing the minimum amount of moves.

[image: Case 1]

> Example 2: in this example it would be possible to move main child and children 4 and 5 to a new wrapper, but this would go against the minimum amount of moves rule. So instead we move main to wrapper 2 and child 3 to a new wrapper.

[image: Case 2]

> Example 3: the minimum amount of moves would be to move main child and child 1 to wrapper 2, but this would go against the rule that the wrapper with lower ids should survive. Which has priority over amount of moves.

[image: Case 3]

Comment: (*Sorting* is often assumed to mean *ordering*, not *categorisation*.)

Comment: A well-defined explicit question is usually expected for this question-answer site. A question mark is supposed to appear somewhere. What is your question?